Seeking assistance with the circuit design for Force balance geophone
I am attempting to DIY this patent article, configuring the circuit based on the method provided (Fig. 1). I've configured the circuit (Figs. 2 and 3 and VIDEO). In my experiment, once I connect the output of amplifier 240 to the circuit, I can indeed sense feedback force with a detector, but the oscilloscope doesn't show any signal as it should be a force balance signal. However, when I remove the output of amplifier 240, I can see waveforms, but obviously, there's no feedback force. I'd like to ask if it's a mistake in my design or if the 240 transconductance amplifier (V TO I) in the figure is an IC instead of an OPA?
Fig. 1
Fig. 2
Fig. 3

No supply capacitors?

Yes, I didn't use supply capacitors. The situation is the same when I power it with batteries, so it shouldn't be related to power supply noise

What are the signals (ouputs of the opamps) on the scope?

The oscilloscope is connected to the output terminals of nodes 570 and 565 in Figure 2. https://youtu.be/ApWgVYdkejg

in the video, when I shake the seismic detector, the oscilloscope reacts when the 240 amplifier is disconnected and does not react when it's connected
